# Docker sql server container and use of windows authentication as login method

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have a simple docker compose with sql server that will look like:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    sqldata:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
        environment:
          - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
          - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        ports:
          - "5433:1433"
        volumes:
          - "./data/:/var/opt/mssql/data/"
          - "./log/:/var/opt/mssql/log/"
          - "./secrets/:/var/opt/mssql/secrets/"
```

Well it works, but as a method of authentication, as above is seen, is user and password. Now I need to change this to Windows Authentication. so I tried adding my user to sql and this happened:

[image]

I have a local instance on mssql database installed (and wanted to move this to docker container) and this works, I can use my local user to authenticate to this server.

I looked for some info, and all solutions was targeted to AD user (as I have no AD, just a local Windows Pro machine with no Windows Server and no AD controller and docker installed). Furthermore I cannot change my project connection string to password and user, it is fixed for authentication.

So is there any way to achieve that on Windows Pro local machine without AD?

Comment: You *need* an AD server for this, as per the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-containers-ad-auth-adutil-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver16): *"The following are required before configuring Active Directory authentication:: Have an Active Directory Domain Controller (Windows) in your network."*

Comment: So no other way, that is unfortunate and sad news.